# How to get only 5 rows with JDBC from ResultSet?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have a select SQL that may get many rows of data.
And I only want the first 5 rows.
Besides adding `rownums = 5` or adding `statement.setMaxRows(5)`.
Can I get the result from using java coding?
Thanks.

I tried for loop and while(rs.next() && i < 5). all of them does not work.

```
    try (Connection connection = abc.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) 
    {
        statement.setString(1,idNum);
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                itemList.add(rs.getString("idName"));                   
            }
        }
    }
```

It shows all of the result in the `itemList` from the select SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, a single iteration of your loop exhausts the whole resultset.

You may want to add up end conditions like :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5 && rs.next(); i++) {

    itemList.add(rs.getString("idName"));                   

}
```

Note that your attempt with `while(rs.next() && i < 5)` should also work, you were probably just missing the increment of `i` .

Answer (score 2):

You can read only the first 5 rows from the resultSet on the client side, but ideally you should be limiting number of rows returned by the database. Use `limit 5` in the query.

This will avoid a lot of unnecessary work needed to return those extra rows from the database to client.

Comment: yes. that should be the easiest solution. but just wonder how to solve with coding in java. thanks for your suggestion:)

Answer (score 2):

Your query is responsible to fetch data from DB , so better to control retrieve rows from db itself,  this will avoid your java code checks. use limit 5 in your query based on your requirements.